# Shopping Cart Error :: Cannot add items to the "Shopping Cart Page " :: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript, html, json, e-commerce

I am busy doing a task creating a shopping cart via HTML, CSS and Javascript. I have been following a Youtube tutorial, but there seems to be a glitch somewhere and, after trying a couple of things, I still receive the following error:

```
**main.js:76 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at onLoadCartNumbers (main.js:76)
    at main.js:173
onLoadCartNumbers @ main.js:76
(anonymous) @ main.js:173**
```

I think that it might be that in console, the first time you add an item to the cart, the first output is 0. I tried targeting this, but have not had any success. I am unfortunately, due to this error, not able to add the items to display on the "Shopping Cart" page and cannot move forward with the task.

Please see the Code Snippet below:

https://jsfiddle.net/ChanelleB/cwmzs20b/

In addition, please see below the code for the "Shopping Cart" HTML content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="top_nav">
        <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" id="logo" />

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
            <a href="Catalogue.html">Catalogue</a>
            <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <span id="hamburger" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

        <div id="search_bar">
            <input type="search" placeholder="search..." />
            <button><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>

        <a href="ShoppingCart.html" class="button" id="add-to-cart-button">
            <ion-icon name="trolley"></ion-icon><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cart"> Cart:</i><span
                class="amount-products">0</span>
        </a>
    </nav>

    <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product-header">
            <h5 class="product-title">PRODUCT</h5>
            <h5 class="price">PRICE</h5>
            <h5 class="quantity">QUANTITY</h5>
            <h5 class="total">TOTAL</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="products">

        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p> &copy; Hyperion Development.&nbsp;&nbsp; All Rights Reserved.&nbsp;&nbsp; Proudly created by <a
                href="http://www.hyperiondev.com">Hyperion Development</a></p>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would appreciate any assistance that anyone is willing to offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the behavior of the **`document.querySelector()`** function requires that the *DOM is ready and parsed*, you could add this to your JS file and  call your js files from wherever you like:

```
// my-script.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    // this function runs when the DOM is ready, i.e. when the document has been parsed
    document.querySelector('input[type=file]')
        .addEventListener('change', function(event){
            ...
         }
});
```

Also take a look at the documentation to resolve any doubts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I also realized that I made a "propductContainer" spelling mistake. Not my finest moment, but so we learn.